# Any way to draw a curve by hand and use the data and fit a function on data?

Tags: fitting

I'd like to draw a simple curve by hand. 
Next, I have to figure out what function defines it the best.

I've been thinking long but I don't have an idea how to make it.

What I could imagine is that somehow draw series of points with drawing tools and get coordinates and then fit an arbitrary function to the coordinates.

In a similar topic someone suggested to use Classify but I don't understand how it helps here.

So I don't know how to start, any idea?

My motivation:
This function would serve as a quantum mechanical wavefunction and I want to make some further calculation with this function as solving time-evolution etc so some physical problem.

Comment: What would be the point of that? Perhaps if you give us some context regarding your final goal, we could help better. In other words, what do you need to do once you have that function? Would fitting a spline work?

Comment: it would be considered as a physical function and I like to use it in further physical problems

Comment: Drawing by hand sounds to me a bit more metaphysical than physical.  And is 2 dimensions enough for a quantum mechanical wave function?

Comment: "What I could imagine is that somehow draw series of points with drawing tools..." There's a button for drawing curve by hand on the drawing tool panel: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGQnN.png

Answer (score 11):

```
Deploy @ DynamicModule[{list = {}, fits = {}}, Panel @ Row[{Framed @ 
    EventHandler[Dynamic[Graphics[{Thick, Blue,  Line[list], 
       PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[list]}, PlotRange -> 1, ImageSize -> Medium]], 
     {"MouseDown" :> (list = {}; fits = {};), 
      "MouseDragged" :> (AppendTo[list, MousePosition["Graphics"]]), 
      "MouseUp" :> (fits = FindFormula[list, x, 5, All];)}], 
     Dynamic @ fits}, Spacer[10]]]
```

[image]

You can play with the options of `FindFormula` and show the fit functions as `Epilog`:

```
Deploy @ DynamicModule[{list = {}, fits = {}}, Panel @ Row[{Framed @
   EventHandler[Dynamic[Graphics[{Thick, Opacity[.5, Gray], Line[list], 
     PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[list]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, ImageSize -> Medium, 
     Epilog -> If[fits === {}, {}, 
        First@Plot[Evaluate[Normal[Keys@fits]], {x, 0, 1}]]]], 
   {"MouseDown" :> (list = {}; fits = {};), 
    "MouseDragged" :> (AppendTo[list, MousePosition["Graphics"]]), 
    "MouseUp" :> (fits = FindFormula[list, x, 5, All, 
          TargetFunctions -> {Times,  Plus, Abs, Sin, Cos, Power}];)}], 
    Dynamic[If[fits === {}, "",
      (i = 1; KeyMap[Style[#, 16, ColorData[97][i++]] &]@fits)]]}, 
    Spacer[10]]]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[image]

This does standard fit using Polynomial. You can add more terms to the polynomial and remove term. Can add/remove points. Each point added must be in increasing $x$ order.

Usese `LocatorPane` to collect points and update the fitting Polynomial as more points are added.

```
Manipulate[
 (*Version 1.0 alpha   *)
 tick;
 term = Table[x^n, {n, 0, terms - 1}];
 fit = Fit[collection, term, x];
 Style[TraditionalForm@fit, Medium]
 ,
 Grid[{
   {
    Row[{Button["Add term", {terms++; tick = Not[tick]}, ImageSize -> 100],
     Button["Remove term",{If[terms > 1, terms--]; tick = Not[tick]},ImageSize -> 100],
     Button["Erase All", {collection = {}; tick = Not[tick]}, ImageSize -> 100],
     Button["Erase last", {If[Length@collection > 1,
         collection = Delete[collection, -1]; pt = Last@collection
         ]; tick = Not[tick]}, ImageSize -> 100]}]        
    },     
   {LocatorPane[
     Dynamic[pt, {(pt = #) &,
       (If[Length[collection] > 1,
          If[First@pt >= Max[collection[[All, 1]]],
           AppendTo[collection, pt]
           ]
          ,
          AppendTo[collection, pt]
          ];
         tick = Not[tick]) &}
      ]
     ,
     Dynamic@If[Length[collection] > 1,
       Graphics[
        {
         {First@
           Plot[fit, {x, Min[collection[[All, 1]]], Max[collection[[All, 1]]]},
            PlotStyle -> Red
            ]
          },
         {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[collection]},
         {Blue, Line[collection]}
         },
        ImageSize -> 500,
        PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Axes -> True,
        GridLines -> {Range[-2, 2, .2], Range[-2, 2, .2]},
        GridLinesStyle -> LightGray
        ],
       Graphics[
        {
         {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[collection]},
         {Blue, Line[collection]}
         },
        ImageSize -> 500,
        PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Axes -> True,
        GridLines -> {Range[-2, 2, .2], Range[-2, 2, .2]},
        GridLinesStyle -> LightGray
        ]]]}}, Frame -> True
  ],          
 {{tick, False}, None},
 {{state, "collect"}, None},
 {{pt, {0, 0}}, None},
 {{collection, {}}, None},
 {{fit, 0}, None},
 {{terms, 5}, None},
 ControlPlacement -> Bottom, Alignment -> Center, ImageMargins -> 0,     
 TrackedSymbols :> {tick}
 ]
```